# fillna of running date in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of date and value as follows:

```
date       value
2019-01-01   10
2019-01-02   15
NaT          20
NaT          30
2019-01-05   40
2019-01-06   45
```

How could I automatically fill NaT without predefined 2019-01-03 and 2019-01-04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no duplicated sorted datetimes with correct placed missing values and first with last value is no missing is possible assign back values created by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max())
print (df)
        date  value
0 2019-01-01     10
1 2019-01-02     15
2 2019-01-03     20
3 2019-01-04     30
4 2019-01-05     40
5 2019-01-06     45
```

Another idea is create timedelta ranges for all missing groups and add to last non missing datetime with `ffill`:

```
m = df['date'].isna()
s = pd.to_timedelta(df[m].groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1), unit='d')
df.loc[m, 'date'] = df['date'].ffill() + s
print (df)
        date  value
0 2019-01-01     10
1 2019-01-02     15
2 2019-01-03     20
3 2019-01-04     30
4 2019-01-05     40
5 2019-01-06     45
```